# How to ignore a package during npm audit?

Tags: npm, npm-audit

My `npm audit` report shows [handsontable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/handsontable) as "no fix available".

I am trying to ignore the [handsontable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/handsontable) package by running `npm audit --ignore handsontable` or `npm audit --ignore=handsontable`

It is not ignoring the package.

Is there any flag to ignore certain packages during `npm audit` and `npm audit fix`

Comment: I wonder, what is the Handsontable version that you are auditing? The versions newer or equal 10.0.0 report 0 vulnerabilities on Snyk: https://snyk.io/vuln/npm:handsontable

Also, `npm install handsontable` gives Handsontable 12.0.0, which reports 0 vulnerabilities in npm audit.

Comment: The idea is to prevent handsontable from upgrading. So if you can give me some idea

Answer (score 7):

As of today, 21 Sept 2022, `npm audit` has 2 ways to filter vulnerabilities:

- **audit-level** - sets the minimum level of vulnerability for npm audit to exit with a non-zero exit code.
- **omit** - selects dependency types (dev/prod) to omit from the installation tree on disk.

You can see more about `npm audit` flags [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-audit).

There is no way to ignore specific vulnerabilities yet. I believe npm will have it soon, [the discussion is still ongoing](https://github.com/npm/rfcs/pull/18).

I recommend you to use the npm package `better-npm-audit`. Link [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/better-npm-audit).

You can create a file `.nsprc` and ignore vulnerabilities by ID, CWE ID or GHSA ID as shown below:

```
{
  "1337": {
    "active": true,
    "notes": "Ignored since we don't use xxx method",
    "expiry": 1615462134681
  },
  "4501": {
    "active": false,
    "notes": "Ignored since we don't use xxx method"
  },
  "CWE-471": "CWE ID is acceptable",
  "GHSA-ww39-953v-wcq6": "GHSA ID is acceptable",
  "https://npmjs.com/advisories/1213": "Full or partial URL is acceptable too"
}
```

Comment: The answer is pretty helpful, but it does not answer the question "Is there any flag to ignore certain packages?"